# Joining multiple tables, fixing active record associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple tables

Action:

```
 id
 line_id
 devise_id
 item_id
```

Comment:

```
id
action_id
body
```

item:

```
id
name
```

devise:

```
id
name
```

line:

```
id
name
```

Models:
ActionModel:

```
belongs_to :devise, :foreign_key => 'devise_id'
    belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => 'item_id'
    belongs_to :line, :foreign_key => 'line_id'
    has_many :comments
```

CommentModel:

```
belongs_to :action, :foreign_key => 'item_id'
 has_many :items, through: :actions
```

ItemModel:

```
has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :devises, through: :actions
    has_many :lines, through: :actions
```

DeviseModel:

```
has_many :actions, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :items, through: :actions
    has_many :lines, through: :actions
```

LineModel:

```
  has_many :actions, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :devises, through: :actions
    has_many :lines, through: :actions
    has_many :comments, through: :actions
```

In my actions controller, I want to have something like this:

```
def index
@actions = Action.joins(:item, :comment)
```

to get `action.comment.body` and `action.item.name` in my view.

Can someone advise on whether there's any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this as you already have `action_id` in your `Comment` model

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :action
end
```

You can include the associations

```
@actions = Action.includes(:item, :comments)
```

It will fetch all the comments and item of action.

And you can call

```
action.comments.each do |comment|
  # Loop over the comments
  comment.body
end
# and 
action.item.name
```

Comment: I got undefined method `comment' for #<Action:0x0000000d987e18>

Comment: up[dated my answer

Comment: Thanks but now I got:  undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That means your `action` is `nil`

Comment: I have entries on all tables why do I get nil?

Comment: Added .try(:body) and found out that one entry was nil.. All now fixed. Thanks for your help.